# Estimation of trend unavailable for final observations using Classical Decomposition

Tags: time-series, trend

I'm having a hard time understanding why the trend cannot be estimated for the last several observations in a time series using the Classical Decomposition. I have also read that it can't be used to estimate the first several observations, but this makes more sense to me because one couldn't know if the first observations are trend-related, season-related, or simply have big errors.

Can someone explain the intuition for this?

Comment: Because trends *can* be estimated throughout a time series and beyond (they are the basis of forecasts, after all), could you please explain the sense in which you use the term "trend" and the sense in which you mean it *cannot* be estimated?

Comment: This is simply something I've read in multiple locations. One example is here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/classical-decomposition.html

Comment: You appear to be referring to a *particular procedure* of trend estimation that your reference calls "classical decomposition."  Please include this information within your question.